# PubSub subscription filter

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm trying to set filters in the PubSub subscriptions, one is to order the attributes in the message and the other to add quotes to attributes key and value something like `"key":"value"`. Is this possible?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you asking if it is possible to use filters to alter the attributes?

Comment: Hi @KamalAboul-Hosn, I'm asking if setting such filters like ordering the attributes or adding quotes is possible in pubsub filters and how?

Comment: What do you mean by "ordering the attributes"?

Comment: No, it's not possible to create order in attribute or to change the attribute format.

Comment: @KamalAboul-Hosn, ordering of attributes - if a,b,c are the attributes coming from pubsub source, I always want the subscription of this topic to receive the attributes in the same order (a,b,c)

Answer (score 0):

Filters cannot change messages, including attribute order or attribute contents. The filters only allow one to set match criteria for attributes such that only messages that match those criteria are delivered to the subscribers. The attributes in a messages are a map from a string key to a value string, not a list. Therefore, there can be no guarantees on the ordering of the attributes. Many languages these days randomize the order when iterating through a map so one does not depend on the order in such data structures.